# Listview to pull up button/widget

Tags: listview, button, flutter, scroll

I have simple listview example here with bottomNavigationBar, I need to when listview reach end(bootom scroll) new button to show up. Should i put button inside listview somehow or there is other way?

here is complete example so Test button to show up on end of scrolling not all the time..

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'listview_column.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      //home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      home: ListViewColumn(),
    );
  }
}
```

listview class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ListViewColumn extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> _listViewData = [
    "A List View with many Text - Here's one!",
    "A List View with many Text - Here's another!",
    "A List View with many Text - Here's more!",
    "A List View with many Text - Here's more!",
    "A List View with many Text - Here's more!",
    "A List View with many Text - Here's more!",
    "A List View with many Text - Here's one!",
    "A List View with many Text - Here's another!",
    "A List View with many Text - Here's more!",
    "A List View with many Text - Here's more!",
    "A List View with many Text - Here's more!",
    "A List View with many Text - Here's more!",
    "A List View with many Text - Here's one!",
    "A List View with many Text - Here's another!",
    "A List View with many Text - Here's more!",
    "A List View with many Text - Here's more!",
    "A List View with many Text - Here's more!",
    "A List View with many Text - Here's more!",
    "A List View with many Text - Here's one!",
    "A List View with many Text - Here's another!",
    "A List View with many Text - Here's more!",
    "A List View with many Text - Here's more!",
    "A List View with many Text - Here's more!",
    "A List View with many Text - Here's more!",
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('ListView in Column Example'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[

          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              children: _listViewData.reversed.map((data) {
                return Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text(data),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('test'),
            onPressed: (){},
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(121, 85, 72, 1.0),
        child: Container(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[

              InkWell(
                  splashColor: Color.fromRGBO(78, 53, 43, 0),
                  highlightColor: Color.fromRGBO(78, 53, 43, 1),
                  onTap: () {

                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 15.0, bottom: 15.0, left: 40.0, right: 40.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Finish - Create Report',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                    ),
                  )),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the Column with a SingleChildScrollView. The button will always appear at the end of the ListView's scroll.

```
/* Scaffold */
body: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            ListView(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: _listViewData.reversed.map((data) {
                return Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text(data),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('test'),
              onPressed: (){},
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
/* Scaffold */
```

Comment: This one seams to be best for my case and simplest tnx all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ScrollController` with a listener so when you attain the end of your list you add your button to your `_listViewData` using a setState. (Don't forget to add the controller to your ListView)

```
ScrollController controller;

@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = ScrollController()..addListener(_scrollListener);
}

_scrollListener() {
    if (controller.position.pixels == controller.position.maxScrollExtent) {
      addButtonToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: tnx ,but how do i implement addButtonToList(); to show button and push listview above or to integrate in listview?

Comment: I would create a List<Widget> containing your ListView that will be the children of your Column widget and then the method addButtonToList() would be adding the button to your widget list and call setState to update the view.

Answer (score 0):

With Dart 2.5 you can do this:

```
ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    ..._listViewData,
      FlatButton(
        child: Text('test'),
          onPressed: (){},
        ),
    ]
)
```